# Comparing mean of the same group in two different years?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, t-test, panel-data, model

I have a dataset about a group of people that was collected in two consecutive years (2013 and 2014). This dataset have several variables and one of them is income.

Make sense do a hypothesis test to compare the mean income of the same group of people in two different years?

In this case I have data of the same population for two years, would be the case of use a longitudinal model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use t-test paired to compare the mean income of the same group of people in two different years

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test) you can read more about paired t-test in this link.

if you are using R [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/paired-students-t-test/) << this link will help